# NServiceBus with Oracle Tables transport

Tags: oracle, nservicebus

Is it possible to replace MSMQ with Oracle tables as a transport mechanism?  if so, can someone point me to info on configuring nsb as such.

Thanks.

Comment: There has been some work on an Oracle Advanced Queuing transport by the community - here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.OracleAQ/

Answer (score 1):

There is no Oracle transport for NServiceBus out of the box, at least as of 4.0.

Implementing one would be conceptually very much like the SQL Server transport. You could take a look at the [SQL Server transport source](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/tree/4.0.4/src/SqlServer) and build a similar implementation for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for https://github.com/rosieks/NServiceBus.OracleAQ ?